# Breaking a Python URL generated w/ several variables back into components

Tags: python, python-2.7, variables

I'm declaring a variable thus:

```
url = baseUrl + urlParam(pair[1].value, conditionMapping[pair[0].value])
```

where:

```
baseUrl = 'http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?'
conditionMapping = {'New': '1000', 'New Other': '1000', 'Used': '12'}

def urlParam(product, condition):
    return urlencode({'_from':'R40',
                       '_sacat':'0',
                       '_nkw':product,
                       'LH_Complete':'1',
                       'LH_Sold':'1',
                       'rt':'nc',
                      '_sop':'3',
                      'LH_BIN':'1',
                      'LH_ItemCondition' : condition})
```

and `pair[0]` and `pair[1]` are values taken from a cells of a spreadsheet using openpyxl.

This results in the program generating URLs like:

**http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?rt=nc&LH_Complete=1&_nkw=Columbia+Hiking+Pants&LH_Sold=1&_sacat=0&LH_BIN=1&_from=R40&_sop=3&LH_ItemCondition=1000**

What I wish to do now is whenever a request to one of these URLs fails, I want to be able to 'reverse engineer' the URL, with to find out what the value of pair[0] and pair[1] (product condition and product name respectively) were for that URL. Given knowledge of how the `url` variable was constructed, is it possible to do so? Alternativley, is there a better way to set up my variable (and/or indeed the other inputs) to facilitate this?

Comment: You don't need to "reverse engineer" anything. Just save the original structure somewhere.

Comment: You mean something along the lines of creating an empty dict, and each time a url is contructed, store a new key/value pair where k and v are the urls and inputs?

Comment: This isn't just any "variable formed from several inputs" -- in the general case, which is what the topic asks for, it's impossible. What you actually request in the text, on the other hand, is a *specific* case of parsing out a URL. Edit your topic to be clear on that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> urlparse.parse_qs(urlparse.urlparse('''http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?rt=nc&LH_Complete=1&_nkw=Columbia+Hiking+Pants&LH_Sold=1&_sacat=0&LH_BIN=1&_from=R40&_sop=3&LH_ItemCondition=1000''').query)
{'rt': ['nc'], 'LH_Complete': ['1'], '_nkw': ['Columbia Hiking Pants'], 'LH_Sold': ['1'], '_sacat': ['0'], 'LH_BIN': ['1'], '_from': ['R40'], '_sop': ['3'], 'LH_ItemCondition': ['1000']}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do your URL processing in your function that handles the URL, and use a `try/catch` block to return those values if it fails. For example:

```
def doStuffWithURL(firstParam,secondParam):
    url = baseUrl + urlParam(firstParam, conditionMapping[secondParam])
    try:
        #whatever you were doing
        response = requests.get(url)
    except Exception, e:
        print e
```

Or (preferred method) catch your specific exception, and let others raise errors:

```
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError, e:
         print e
```

Comment: Gets a well-deserved upvote for outside-the-box thinking.